# How do I make xscreensaver run on startup?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, chromium

I have a raspberry pi running raspbian which is started via the following line in .profile

xinit /usr/bin/chromium --kiosk --incognito www.myweb.com

however after about 10-15 mins the screen goes blank and nothing I try has managed to stop this.... However I have found a possible solution using xscreensaver. I have installed xscreensaver and then disabled it, I just now need to start xscreensaver before chromium runs.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried "xset s off" to disable the screen saver?

Answer (score 0):

LXDE's startup script is located in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart.

You can add anything you like there so that it starts with the system. Just be sure to add a **@** symbol in front of the line.I am running xscreensaver and a few other applications on boot.

This thread [here](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=111) may give you some insights into defining startup applications.

Hope this helps!